# Find text in string use javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I want find text in string and print text to ouput use javascript.

I have a text

> Changes: -rw-r--r-- (644)

I want get number in () from this text and print it to alert()

So, how i can do that. Thanks you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261243/find-text-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
var m = 'Changes: -rw-r--r-- (644)'.match(/\d+/);
var num = m && m[0];
console.log(num);
```

It matches the first group of digits in the given string, and extracts those. If no digits were found, `num` will be `null`.

Note: `alert` is not so user-friendly, so I used `console.log` to show the result.