# Find text javascript

Tags: javascript, text, find

I Have string random length

Ex:

```
 sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds

 sadsadsadsad(321)dfsssds
```

How can I find the values in brackets?.

Value random length

Thank for reading

Comment: What have you tried in order to find them? Have you tried [tag:regex]?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular Expression to get a string between parentheses in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779744/regular-expression-to-get-a-string-between-parentheses-in-javascript)

Comment: I not find regex. Thank you

Comment: You may want to accept the Duplicate, the answers will give you everything you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  This:

```js
var str =  'sadsadsadsad(321)dfss888s(120)ds';

str.match(/\(\d+\)/g).map ( value => { console.log( value.replace(/[)(]/g, '') ) } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try regex `/\(.*\)/`

```js
function getValue(s) {
    var strs = s.match(/\(.*?\)/g);
    if (strs == null) {
        return '';
    }
    return strs.map(str=>str.replace(/[()]/g, ''));
    //return strs.join(' ,').replace(/[()]/g, '')
}



console.log(getValue('sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds(abc)'));
console.log(getValue('sadsad(_d_)sadsad(321)dfsssds'));
console.log(getValue('sadsad(33)sadsad(321dfsssds'));
```

Comment: Thank for help, adsdadsdas(123)adadadad(123431) I need find (123) and (123431) how to?

Comment: @Lightrain125 `adsdadsdas(123)adadadad(123431)` return `123123431` ?

Comment: return 123,123123431

Comment: Your mean is return Array or return string with `,` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastIndexOf` and `substring`

```js
var text = "sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds";
var newText = text.substring(text.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, text.lastIndexOf(")"));

console.log(newText)
```

Comment: Thank for help, 

adsdadsdas(123)adadadad(123431)

I need find (123) and (123431) how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` and `substring`

```js
let str = 'sadsadsadsad(321)dfsssds';

let getFirstIndex = str.indexOf('(');
let getSecondIndex = str.indexOf(')');

let subStr = str.substring(getFirstIndex + 1, getSecondIndex);
console.log(subStr)
```

Comment: Thank for help, 

adsdadsdas(123)adadadad(123431)

I need find (123) and (123431) how to?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds"; 
var val= str.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
if (val) {
    console.log("found");
 }
```

You can use Regex

```
var str = "sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds"; 
var val= str.match(/\((.*?)\)/);
if (val) {
    console.log("found");
 }
```

Comment: Thank for help, 

adsdadsdas(123)adadadad(123431)

I need find (123) and (123431) how to?

Comment: Please refer to this article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6323417/how-do-i-retrieve-all-matches-for-a-regular-expression-in-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following code it will helps you if you have remove nested Parentheses example  `"a(bcdefghijkl(mno)p)q"`

```
function removeParentheses(s) {
    let openPatterns = [];
    for(let i=0; i < s.length; i++){

        if(s[i] == '('){
            openPatterns.push(i);
        }

        if(s[i] == ')'){
            const lastIndexOpen = openPatterns.pop();
            const originalTxt = s.slice(lastIndexOpen ,i+1);
            //here you have the raw text      
            const rawText = s.slice(lastIndexOpen+1,i);
            //this code works to remove the parentesis 
            //s= s.replace(originalTxt, reverseTxt);
            //i-=2;
        }
    }
    return rawText;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could catch the group within `()` using `replace()`, and passing it to a callback function that push it into an array.

```js
var str = 'sadsadsadsad(323213)dfsssds(1234)dfsssds(4567)dfsssds(abcf)';

var arr = [];

str.replace(/\(([a-z0-9]*)\)+/gi, (a,b)=>arr.push(b));

console.log(arr);
```