# How to use the if comparison function to find the value of a piece of text

Tags: javascript, if-statement, google-apps-script

It is necessary in the operator to compare whether the text contains the value "100" in the answer should be god = 10

```
function myFunctiontest566() {
 var god = 16;
 var test = "test 100 pups"
 if(test == "*100*") {var god = 10;}
 }
```

Comment: use `.indexOf` or regex

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find text javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52261243/find-text-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is indexOf

```
function myFunctiontest566() {
 var god = 16;
 var test = "test 100 pups"
 if(test.indexOf("100")>-1) {var god = 10;}
 }
```